# PST file issues while accessing in windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook, office-interop

In a WinForms application, Microsoft Outlook root folder is accessed to get the profile specific (w.r.t PST file) sub-folders.
Below is code which is used to get root folder from outlook namespace.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application appOutlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
appOutlook.Session.AddStore(sPSTFilePath);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace nsOutlook = appOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
string sSelectedPSTFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sPSTFilePath);
MAPIFolder rootFolder = nsOutlook.Stores[sSelectedPSTFileName].GetRootFolder();
```

It is working fine, but on some PST files it throws an exception when It comes to getting root folder from outlook namespace w.r.t PST file name at:

```
MAPIFolder rootFolder = nsOutlook.Stores[sSelectedPSTFileName].GetRootFolder();
```

Exception: The attempted operation failed. An object cannot be found.

I have loaded that PST file in MS Outlook, it is working fine. But, when I access that file from the code it shows exception.

Is there any way to identify that the PST file is corrupted or not ?
Help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: How does Outlook show that PST file in Outlook? Does it use the file name without the ".pst" extension? Or does it use a display name?

Comment: It shows file name without extension.

Comment: what happens if you loop through the Namespace.Stores collection? Is the new store there? Does it have the expected name?  I can only suggest using Redemption - its RDOSession.Stores.AddPstStore method returns ad instance of the RDOPstStore object without the need to access it by name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way

```
OutLook.MAPIFolder outlook_Folder = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace nsOutlook = appOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
outlook_Folder =nsOutlook.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Parent;
Console.WriteLine("Root Folder: " + outlook_Folder.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to identify if a PST file is corrupted.

1. Check the file size- A corrupted PST file size will be different from the original file size due to the data discrepancy issue.
2. If you are unable to open file in Outlook that denotes 'Data file is corrupted'.
3. Run scanPST or any third party tool to scan your PST file and it will show if it's corrupted.
4. While accessing root folder of PST file in your code, if you are getting error that means your PST file might be corrupted.